# Request failing error message when passing data from react application to web service

Tags: spring, reactjs, axios

I have a javascript object and when I stringify It, I get the data below which 
is called dataToJson

```
    0: {invoiceId: 45233265}
    1: {invoiceId: 89238545}
    2: {invoiceId: 65235465}
```

Here is my endpoint written with spring.io which should  accept the json data
above. I decided not to include all the code in the method because it works. 
All I need is how to pass the data.

```
    @ApiOperation(
            value = "Returns a pageable list of data.",
            notes = "Must be authenticated.")
    @EmptyNotFound
    @GetMapping({
            "customers/{customerId}/getProductsForInvoices/{invoiceIds}"
    })
    public ArrayList<Page<CustomerInvoiceProduct>> getProductsForInvoices(
            @PathVariable(required = false) Long customerId,
            @RequestBody List<CustomerInvoice> invoiceIds,
            Pageable pageInfo) {

        ......
        ......

        return result;
    }
```

Here is how I am using Axios to make the web service call and pass in the data.

```
     AXIOS_AUTHED.get(`${API}/customers/${getCustomerId}/getProductsForInvoices/invoiceIds`, { 
        params:dataToJson
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(dataToJson);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(dataToJson);
      });
```

All I get is "request failed with status code 400"

When I pass data like this from postman, it works very well.

```
    [
      {
        "invoiceId":"45233265"
      },
      {
        "invoiceId":"89238545"
      },
      {
        "invoiceId":"65235465"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: How did you test it on Postman? What did the url look like?

Comment: Same url like this http://localhost:8020/api/v1/customers/1329/getProductsForInvoices/invoiceIds and I passed the json data above. I put the json data in the body section

Comment: I don't know Spring but shouldn't `invoiceIds` be something you pass in and not actually part of the url? Much like `customerId`?

Comment: Or maybe you need to send it as data. Something like `data:{"invoiceIds": dataToJson}`

Comment: I can try what you suggested.

Comment: Nothing i have tried works at the moment. Any other idea?

Comment: What about `data: dataToJson`? Without the `invoiceIds` keys using the url that works for you on Postman